# Why does it ask me to wait for 2 days to accept my own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I posted a question about an error message while trying to importing a file in python and no one posted their answers but I searched online and get to know the solution and it worked well and I wish to share this information. So I answered my own question.
But when I try to accept my own answer It asking me to wait for 2 days.
my question is "why should I've to wait for two days since I know the correct answer".
Is there any other logic behind this?

Comment: The bottom line is: you won't gain anything from accepting your own answer (so, no need to rush it) but you _might_ learn something new if people are encouraged to answer the question.